# Rails - How to secure foreign keys and still allow association selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security

For simplicity, assume that I have a simple has-many-through relationship

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, :through => :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :registrations
end
```

I want to keep my app secure, so I use `attr_accessible` to whitelist my attributes.

My question is twofold:

1. How would I set up my whitelist attributes such that I could create a new Registration object through a form (passing in `:user` and `:course`, but not risk allowing those foreign keys to be maliciously updated later?
2. How would I set up my validations such that both `belongs_to` associations are required BUT also allow for Registration objects to be created in nested forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to first question

One solution is you could mark `:user` and `:course` as readonly.

```
attr_readonly :user_id, :course_id
```

This way it will be possible to set them on create, but not on update. If you want them to be updatable in the future, you could create a special method on your registration model along the lines of `@registration.update_dangerous_stuff(params)` and only use this method in a controller action accessible by users with higher privilege. The method would use something along the lines of `update_column` to alter these fields.

Another approach could be to create virtual attributes for setting the user and course, that have logic deciding whether right now user or course can be set. Here's an example.

```
attr_accessor :safe_user, :safe_course
attr_accessible :safe_user, :safe_course


before_save :set_user, if: 'user.blank?'
before_save :set_course, if: 'course.blank?'


def set_user
  self.user = safe_user
end

def set_course
  self.course = safe_course
end
```

And so in the form you would use `safe_user` and `safe_course` fields instead of `user` and `course`. In this case it would only set the actual `user` and `course` if they're blank, and they're never actually exposed as accessible. You can make this rule bypassable by playing with callback conditions.

### Answer to second question

When you submit a bunch of data in a complex form it's up to you to come up with a way to tell which of this data is meaningful and which is just a placeholder. Simply don't create a registration if no meaningful data was submitted. You have to decide which form fields are "enough" to see that somebody actually tried filling them and made mistakes, versus the case where somebody never even touched the nested form. If there is no easy way to determine that - one way to do that would be to add a checkbox "add this registration" to the nested form. If that checkbox is checked - creation will be attempted and validations will run. Afterwards, you could add some javascript to hide this checkbox and check it automatically if a person activated any of the fields in the nested form.

In order to facilitate this behavior on the back end, you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` [rails method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). You could say something like the following in the course model for example.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrations,
  reject_if: -> attrs { attrs[:name].blank? }

# Don't forget this too 
attr_accessible :registrations_attributes
```

Rails also provides a shortcut.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrations, reject_if: :all_blank
```

In the case of checkbox, you could say `reject_if: -> attrs { attrs[:my_check_box] == '1' }`, etc.

Having `reject_if` tells rails that if the conditions in the given proc are not met, it will simply ignore the registration, instead of trying to create and validate it.

Hope this gives you some ideas to play around with.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the thorough answer! It seems that I was unclear in my second question -

I can set up the Schedules model validations to ensure that `:user_id` and `:course_id` are both (`validates :presence => true`), which makes sense when I am creating a new Schedule object.  

However, if I also want to be able to create a Schedule object as a nested attribute along with the User object creation, it throws an error (since I can't pass in the `:user_id` of an object that still hasn't been saved).

Can I set up that validation to allow both cases?